# Multiple filter criteria on Room data before UI

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm working on a project now, where I have implemented MVVM + LiveData + Repository + Clean architecture.
Data are request from the Room DB, but in the screen, I have 2 filter criteria : filter by name or date. They can be used together or individually.
The room DB just send all the data without any filter, and if the user doesn't choose a filter option, it's fine.
But if the user filters data on name and/or date, how should I filter those data? Should I have to query the data from Room every time that 
filter changes, and then apply a transformation.map() to my data (received from Room) in the UseCase for example? Is it better to perform the Room query just the first time,
and after that treat my data as I want in the ViewModel without doing other Room queries? Do I have to write SQL requests for each filter option?

And if I have to filter my data in UseCase, it's easy with one filter option. For two filter criteria, I can manage that with if statements. But if there are five filter criteria, it will
be a bit difficult to manage that with if statements. So again, what is the best way to implement multiple filters in the UseCase?

Do you know any github project where a similar feature is implemented?

PS: I'm a junior Android developer, starting with Kotlin, experienced in Java.

Comment: Hey @frednm, in my opinion, if the data remains the same fetching it again from room database won't be a good approach since its just the different representation you need on your UI with the same data. For better management, I would suggest you can create a 'IntDef' or StringDef and pass it to your UseCase and use a switch case of this IntDef/StringDef and return data. Also, it will be neat solution if you have many more filters in future. Happy to chat more.